# HandleClick using React JS not Working with bind

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code for react

```
handleRemoveClick = material => {
  let idMaterial = material.material_id;
  if(this.state.operation === 0){
    this.setState( { previewShowAlertRemoveProduct : true })
    }
    this.setState( { operation : 1, material_id : idMaterial})
}



handleEndOrder(){
  if(this.state.operation === 0){
    this.setState( { previewShowAlertRemoveProduct : true })
    }
    this.setState( { operation : 2})
}
```

This is for Render the View:

```
  <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger pull-right"  onClick={e => this.handleRemoveClick(material)}>x</button>
```

How to fix this ?  onClick it's not working at all
I have binded in the constructor the `handleEndOrder`

Comment: what do you mean onClick is not working

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri The functions it's not called when i click in button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't specified the type on button, it is by default `submit`, you need to either specify the `type="button"` or use `e.preventDefault()` like

```
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger pull-right" type="button" onClick={e => this.handleRemoveClick(material)}>x</button>
```

or

```
handleRemoveClick = (e, material) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let idMaterial = material.material_id;
  if(this.state.operation === 0){
    this.setState( { previewShowAlertRemoveProduct : true })
    }
    this.setState( { operation : 1, material_id : idMaterial})
}
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger pull-right"  onClick={e => this.handleRemoveClick(e, material)}>x</button>
```

Comment: So in case i want to call the handleEndOrder i only need define .bind in constructor and type button ?

Comment: Glad to have helped :-)